# Posting the form with the user's input on the same page with php

Tags: php

I am quite new to PHP so I need some help with my project.

I have a form on the page where the user writes its content and name, like this:

```
<div class="white shadow padding-10 margin-bottom">
 <form class="form xl relative" method="POST" action="
 <?php  echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>
 ">
   <div class="col-1 col-persist -margin">
     <img class="pull-left width-100 round" src="images/logo.gif" alt = "logo"/>
   </div>
   <div class="col-9 col-persist gutter-h-10 padding-top-5 -margin">
     <textarea  placeholder="What is new?" name="content"></textarea>
     <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="What is your name?">
   </div>
   <div class="col-2 col-persist -margin">
     <input type="button" name="submit" value="Send">
   </div>
 </form>
</div>
```

PHP_SELF I use to stay on the same page

In php part I have this:

```
$userName = "";
$userInput = "";
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] === "POST"){
  $userName = $_POST['name'];
  $userInput = $_POST["content"];
}

  if(isset($_POST)){
   echo '<div class="white shadow padding-10 margin-bottom">';
   echo '<form class="form xl relative" method="POST">';
   echo '<div class="col-1 col-persist -margin">';
   echo '<img class="pull-left width-100 round" src="images/logo.gif" alt = "logo"/>';
   echo '</div>';
   echo '<div class="col-9 col-persist gutter-h-10 padding-top-5 -margin">';
   echo '<textarea  placeholder="What's new?" name="content">'.$userInput.'</textarea>';
   echo '</div>';
   echo '<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="What's your name?">'.$userName;
   echo '</div>';
   echo '</form>';
   echo '</div>';
  }
```

However, this code does not work at all. When debugging, the browser shows some problem in these lines:

```
echo '<textarea  placeholder="What's new?" name="content">'.$userInput.'</textarea>';
echo '</div>';
echo '<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="What's your name?">'.$userName;
```

What is the problem? I guess it is something in syntax, but maybe more in code logic itself?
Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Problem is with Single quote inside the echo statement. You will need to escape them using escape character wherever required like this `echo '<textarea  placeholder="What\'s new?" name="content">'.$userInput.'</textarea>';`

Comment: you have to escape your apostrophes by prepending a backward slash `\'`

Comment: in the code above you have an apostrophe in `What's new?` which breaks the formatting - you need to escape the apostrophe

Comment: you are not concatenating the strings correctly e.g ` echo '<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="What's your name?">'` should be  echo '<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="What\'s your name?">' and so on with other apostrophes

Comment: Thanks, I corrected it by reformulating the questions without apostrophes, but the code does not work :(

Comment: is that all the code involved? I don't see a closing form tag ( in the PHP part that is )

Comment: When the form is submitted is the text input supposed to display the POSTed `$userName` - if so you need to use the value attribute for the text input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First your form needs a submit button, so change `<input type="button" name="submit" value="Send">` to `<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send">`

Also, you don't need to use `PHP_SELF`, simply leaving the action attribute as `action=""` will keep it on the same page.

As for the error in the php, you have single quote marks that are not escaped. This should work:

```
echo '<textarea  placeholder="What\'s new?" name="content">'.$userInput.'</textarea>';
echo '</div>';
echo '<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="What\'s your name?">'.$userName;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `<input type='submit' name='submit' value='send'>` in your html and not button.